# jQuery click event not working on multiple screens

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.4

I am using jQuery 1.4.2. 
Using the CSS selector "span.accordionOn", I am handling a click event.
On screen one, it is working fine. Where as when I navigate to next screen, the functions are not getting called.

The jQuery handlers are as shown below. I am keeping them in a js file and loading the js file for every page load.

```
 $("span.accordionOn").click(function(event){
    $(this).parents(".toggleOuterCustom");
    $(this).parents(".toggleOuterCustom").find(".lHeight").toggleClass('lHeighttranslate');
    return false;
  });




// toggle link icon
  $('span.accordionOn').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('accordionOff');
  });
```

Comment: Show the page load code? this is probably where your problem lies.

Comment: maybe create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing more code it will be hard to find the exact issue, but here's a guess:

```
 $(document).on("click", "span.accordionOn", function(event){
    $(this).toggleClass('accordionOff'); //I merged the 2 functions
    $(this).parents(".toggleOuterCustom");
    $(this).parents(".toggleOuterCustom").find(".lHeight").toggleClass('lHeighttranslate');
    return false;
  });
```

Try the above code. If this works then the issue is as following:

- You bind the event handler to all `span.accordionOn` elements that are currently in the document
- However, if you add new `span.accordionOn` elements **after** this, the event will not be bound to them
- The `on` event will work for all current and future `span.accordionOn` items that will ever be in the document, which solves this issue

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.  yes, you are right, elements do not exist when I am trying to bind.

However with jQuery 1.4.2, 'on()' doesn't exist and used 'live'. Here is the code.

```
  $("span.accordionOn").live('click',function(event){
    $(this).parents(".toggleOuterCustom");
    $(this).parents(".toggleOuterCustom").find(".lHeight").toggleClass('lHeighttranslate');
    return false;
  });
```

Comment: Is there perhaps a reason why you are using an outdated jQuery version? If not, I suggest upgrading to the newest stable version.